# Convert a string or html file to C# HtmlDocument without using WebBrowser or HAP

Tags: c#, browser, dom

The only solution I could find was using:

```
            mshtml.HTMLDocument htmldocu = new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
            htmldocu .createDocumentFromUrl(url, "");
```

and I am not sure about the performance, it should be better than loading the html file in a WebBrowser and then grab the HtmlDocument from there. Anyhow, that code does not work on my machine. The application crashes when it tries to execute the second line.

Has anyone an approach to achieve this efficiently or any other way?

NOTE: Please understand that I need the HtmlDocument object for DOM processing. I do not need the html string.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DownloadString` method of the `WebClient` object. e.g.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string reply = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

In the above example, after executed, `reply` will contain the html markup of the endpoint `http://www.google.com`.

[WebClient.DownloadString MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The idea is getting the HtmlDocument object for DOM parsing, and not the string of the html. Webclient will just return the html string, and not the HtmlDocument.

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to answer your *actual question* from four years ago (at the time of me posting this answer), I'm providing a working solution. I wouldn't be surprised if you found another way to do this, either, so this is mostly for other people searching for a similar solution. Keep in mind, however, that this is considered

1. somewhat obsolete (the actual use of `HtmlDocument`)
2. not the best way to handle HTML DOM parsing (the preferred solution is to use HtmlAgilityPack or CsQuery or some other method using actual parsing and not regular expressions)
3. *extremely* hacky and therefore not the safest/most compatible way to do it
4. you really *should not* be doing what I'm about to show

Additionally, keep in mind that `HtmlDocument` is really just a wrapper for `mshtml.HTMLDocument2`, so it is *technically* slower than just using a COM wrapper directly, but I completely understand the use case simply for ease of coding.

If you're cool with all of the above, here's how to accomplish what you want.

```
public class HtmlDocumentFactory
{
  private static Type htmlDocType = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument);
  private static Type htmlShimManagerType = null;
  private static object htmlShimSingleton = null;
  private static ConstructorInfo docCtor = null;

  public static HtmlDocument Create()
  {
    if (htmlShimManagerType == null)
    {
      // get a type reference to HtmlShimManager
      htmlShimManagerType = htmlDocType.Assembly.GetType(
        "System.Windows.Forms.HtmlShimManager"
        );
      // locate the necessary private constructor for HtmlShimManager
      var shimCtor = htmlShimManagerType.GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[0], null
        );
      // create a new HtmlShimManager object and keep it for the rest of the
      // assembly instance
      htmlShimSingleton = shimCtor.Invoke(null);
    }

    if (docCtor == null)
    {
      // get the only constructor for HtmlDocument (which is marked as private)
      docCtor = htmlDocType.GetConstructors(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
        )[0];
    }

    // create an instance of mshtml.HTMLDocument2 (in the form of 
    // IHTMLDocument2 using HTMLDocument2's class ID)
    object htmlDoc2Inst = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(
      new Guid("25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13")
      ));
    var argValues = new object[] { htmlShimSingleton, htmlDoc2Inst };
    // create a new HtmlDocument without involving WebBrowser
    return (HtmlDocument)docCtor.Invoke(argValues);
  }
}
```

To use it:

```
var htmlDoc = HtmlDocumentFactory.Create();
htmlDoc.Write("<html><body><div>Hello, world!</body></div></html>");
Console.WriteLine(htmlDoc.Body.InnerText);
// output:
// Hello, world!
```

**I have not tested this code directly** -- I have translated it from an old Powershell script that needed the same functionality you're requesting. If it fails, let me know. The functionality is there but the code might need very minor tweaking to get working.